# C#: is there a JTable equivalent?

Tags: c#, winforms, jtable

In C#, is there an equivalent to the Java JTable?
Additionally, I'd like to be able to have rows sorted by column when the user clicks on that column heading.  Finally, I'd like to have two tabs, each with a "JTable" in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
```